# Question about end of request for node/JS request package

Tags: node.js, promise, request

I'm trying to understand what .on('end', ...) does in the node package request.

My code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');

function downloadAsset(relativeAssetURL, fileName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
      var remoteImage = request(`https:${relativeAssetURL}`);
      remoteImage.on('data', function(chunk) {
        writeStream.write(chunk);
      });
      remoteImage.on('end', function() {
        let stats = fs.statSync(fileName);
        resolve({ fileName: fileName, stats: stats });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

What I'm trying to do is download a remote image, get some file statistics, and then resolve the promise so my code can do other things.

What I'm finding is that the promise doesn't always resolve after the file has been downloaded; it may resolve a little before then. I thought that's what .on('end', ... ) was for.

What can I do to have this promise resolve after the image has been downloaded in full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) say:

> The `writable.write()` method writes some data to the stream, and calls the supplied callback once the data has been fully handled.

So, `writable.write()` is *asynchronous*. Just because your last `writeStream.write` has been called does not necessarily mean that all write operations have been completed. You probably want to call the `.end` method, which means:

> Calling the writable.end() method signals that no more data will be written to the Writable. The optional chunk and encoding arguments allow one final additional chunk of data to be written immediately before closing the stream. If provided, the optional callback function is attached as a listener for the 'finish' event.

So, try calling `writeStream.end` when the `remoteImage` request ends, and pass a callback to `writeStream.end` that resolves the `Promise` once the writing is finished:

```
function downloadAsset(relativeAssetURL, fileName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
      const remoteImage = request(`https:${relativeAssetURL}`);
      remoteImage.on('data', function(chunk) {
        writeStream.write(chunk);
      });
      remoteImage.on('end', function() {
        writeStream.end(() => {
          const stats = fs.statSync(fileName);
          resolve({ fileName: fileName, stats: stats });
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

(also try not to mix `var` and `let`/`const` - in an ES6+ environment, prefer `const`, which is generally easier to read and has fewer problems, like hoisting)